# jQuery event triggered many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some "complicated" clicking events that I can't figure it out how to fix it.
I have a click event on some elements added later on the page, so I used `.on`.

What I am trying to achieve is that when you click the .neuron, you shouldn't be able to click another .neuron, or neither the one you clicked before. This is why I added the `.off` function.

The problem is that, after 2-3 times of opening/closing the neuron, the clicking event will trigger 2 times, then 4 times, then 8 times, and so on. I don't understand why.

Here is the part of jQuery is relevant:

```
$("#nn_container").on("click", ".neuron", zoom_neuron);

function zoom_neuron() {

    $("#nn_container").off("click", ".neuron", zoom_neuron);
    console.log("off");

    /* do some stuff */

    $("#close_neuron").click(function() {
        /* do some stuff */
        $("#nn_container").on("click", ".neuron", zoom_neuron);
        console.log("on");
    });
}
```

What is wrong with it? Why it continues to increase in event calling?

Comment: you aren't unbinding from `#close_neuron`'s click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#nn_container").on("click", ".neuron", zoom_neuron);

function zoom_neuron() {

    $("#nn_container").off("click", ".neuron", zoom_neuron);
    console.log("off");

    /* do some stuff */

    $("#close_neuron").off('click').on('click', (function() {
        /* do some stuff */
        $("#nn_container").on("click", ".neuron", zoom_neuron);
        console.log("on");
    });
}
```

That will make sure that `#close_neuron` has only one bound click event at a time. This assumes there are no other places in the code that bind a click event to `#close_neuron`.

Comment: Yep! This has certainly bitten me a number of times too! Feel free to mark the question as answered if it works for you ;)

Comment: Sure I am. Just couldn't yesterday because I had to wait 9 min and I left before them to pass :-) Thanks again!